# worst case runtime of the double for loop

Tags: algorithm, runtime

Can someone please explain how the worst case running time is O(N) and not O(N^2)in the following excercise. There is double for loop, where for every i we need to compare j to i , sum++ and then increment and again repeat the operation until reach N.

What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment
as a function of N?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*2)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sum++;
```

Question Explanation

The answer is : N

The body of the inner loop is executed 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + N ~ 2N times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already stated the answer in your question -- the inner loop is executed 2N times, which is O(N).   In asymptotic (or big-O) notation any multiples are dropped because for very, very large values, the graph of 2N looks just like N, so it isn't considered significant.  In this case, the complexity of the problem is equal to the number of times "sum++" is called, because the algorithm is so simple. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, yes I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

**Complexity doesn't depends upon number of nested loops**

```
it is O(Nc):
 Time complexity of nested loops is equal to the number of times the
innermost statement is executed.

For example the following sample loops have O(N2) time complexity
```

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i += c) {
       for (int j = 1; j <=n; j += c) {
          // some O(1) expressions
       }
   }

   for (int i = n; i > 0; i += c) {
       for (int j = i+1; j <=n; j += c) {
          // some O(1) expressions
   }
```